# Use Beautiful Soup findall to extract text between single quotations

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, findall

I'm using Beautiful Soup and  I want to extract the text within '' with the findall method.

```
content = urllib.urlopen(address).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, from_encoding='utf-8')
soup.prettify()
x = soup.findAll(do not know what to write)
```

An extract from soup as an example:

```
<td class="leftCell identityColumn snap" onclick="fundview('Schroder
European Special Situations');" title="Schroder European Special
Situations"> <a class="coreExpandArrow" href="javascript:
void(0);"></a> <span class="sigill"><a class="qtpop"
href="/vips/ska/all/sv/quicktake/redirect?perfid=0P0000XZZ3&amp;flik=Chosen">
<img
src="/vips/Content/corestyles/4pSigillGubbe.gif"/></a></span>
<span class="bluetext" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow:
hidden;">Schroder European Spe..</span>
```

I would like the result from `soup.findAll(do not know what to write)` to be: `Schroder European Special Situations` and the findall logic should be based on that it is the text between single quotation marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locate the `td` element and get the `onclick` attribute value - the `BeautifulSoup`'s job at this point would be completed. The next step would be to extract the desired text from the attribute value - let's use regular expressions for that. Implementation:

```
import re

onclick = soup.select_one("td.identityColumn[onclick]")["onclick"]

match = re.search(r"fundview\('(.*?)'\);", onclick)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Alternatively, it looks like the `span` with `bluetext` class has the desired text inside:

```
soup.select_one("td.identityColumn span.bluetext").get_text()
```

---

Also, make sure you are using the [4th `BeautifulSoup` version](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and your import statement is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```